# a phrase/word for a place that looks good decor wise but bad products wise

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a phrase/word for a place which looks good decor wise but bad products wise.

Context: I went to a coffee shop that looked stunning but their products and service were not good.
And my sentence is: The coffee shop was ___________.

My original thought was cosmetic, but someone told me is it not appropriate here.

What would you use in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you also fill in the blank with words or phrases that you think would fit (and why they weren't a good fit in your opinion). Otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: @rajah9, thanks. I just edited it.

Answer (score 2):

To be "all show" or "all image" would suggest something which is all about the outward appearance and not the inward reality. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/show) define "all show" as "An outward display intended to give a false impression."

"style over substance" fits the case well: it refers to valuing looks over content. It's a commonly used phrase ([random example](https://www.thetelegraphandargus.co.uk/news/10812039.its-style-over-substance-with-dull-all-star-drama/)) but I can't find it in most dictionaries: [EnglishBaby has a brief definition](https://www.englishbaby.com/vocab/word/10999/style-over-substance)

The best expression would depend on if the place is particularly well-designed or merely draws the eye through lots of colours and decoration and fashionable things. There are other expressions for a place which is garish, ostentatious, and perhaps vulgar in its appearance with nothing of substance behind. This includes idioms like the British "[all fur coat and no knickers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_fur_coat_and_no_knickers)" (defined in [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+all+fur+coat+and+no+knickers) as "To be attractive on the surface but lack substance underneath."), but this might be vulgar to some or obscure to non-British people.

"Showy" is somewhat similar - [Merriam-Webster's usage note](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/showy#synonym-discussion) says "SHOWY, PRETENTIOUS, OSTENTATIOUS mean given to excessive outward display.  SHOWY implies an imposing or striking appearance but usually suggests cheapness or poor taste."

["Meretricious"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meretricious) is defined by one dictionary as "seeming attractive but really false or of little value"; it originally referred to prostitutes, and MW suggests it typically refers to vulgar or garish displays, so it may or may not fit.

Comment: Ahhh, "all show" and "style over substance"! Great idioms

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I want to learn English with you, OMG. Do you teach somewhere, like on italki?

Comment: By the way, the place is well-designed.

Answer (score 1):

I would be descriptive, at the sake of conciseness, so as to help the readers. Something like:

> The coffee shop was aesthetically pleasing but lacked quality service and products. [describe why the service and products lack quality here].

If you really want to be concise:

> The coffee shop was purely/merely aesthetic.